# Chisel randomly initialize register value when simulating with verilator

Tags: chisel, verilator

I'm using Chisel and blackbox to run my chisel logic against a verilog register file.
The registerfile does not have reset signal so I expect the register to be randomly initialized.

I passed the `--x-initial unique` to verilator,
Basically this is how I launch the test:

```scala
  private val backendName = "verilator"

  "NOCDMA" should s" do blkwrite and blkread correctly (with $backendName)" in {
    Driver.execute(Array("--fint-write-vcd","--backend-name",s"$backendName",
      "--more-vcs-flags","--trace-depth 1 --x-initial unique"),
      ()=>new DMANetworkWithMem(memAddrWidth,memDataWidth)(nocDataWidth)(nNodesX,nNodesY)){
      c => new DMANetworkRWTest(c)
    }
  }
```

But The data I read from the register file is all zero before I wrote anything to it.

The read data is correct after I wrote to it.

So, is there anything inside chisel that I need to tune or I did not do everything properly ?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain, but I found the following issue on Verilator with a similar issue: https://github.com/verilator/verilator/issues/1399.

From skimming the above issue, I think you also need to pass `+verilator+seed+<value>` and `+verilator+rand+reset+<value>` at runtime. I am not an expert in the iotesters, but I believe you can add these runtime values through the iotesters argument: `--more-vcs-c-flags`.

Side note, I would also set `--x-assign unique` in Verilator if there are cases in the Verilog where runtime would otherwise inject an X (eg. out-of-bounds index).

I hope this helps!

Comment: but the "--more-vcs-c-flags" is used for g++'s option which make g++ complain that g++: error: +verilator+seed+1: No such file or directory ... do you mean to run the compiled verilator executable with those options? How to do that within Chisel?

Comment: Yeah you're right, so that's not the right way to pass runtime arguments. I don't really know of a great way, but it looks like there's an option to set the runtime command `--test-command`. I don't see a way to edit the existing command, but it defaults to just `<path>/<to>/V<top name>` (https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-testers/blob/f410c59316e5c43bac96411889aba8c5ab9a8fc0/src/main/scala/chisel3/iotesters/VerilatorBackend.scala#L281) so you could duplicate that logic and add the arguments to that command-line argument.

Comment: Yeah, --test-command works with constant "V<TopName>". Yet it seems very unlikely to get the topName from the "circuit.name" since the module must be instantiated inside "Builder context", But Builder is private and cannot be accessed. Any idea how to use the module name (the getClass.getName method for some class) rather than hand written constant ?